# Anybody can help me to do merge as shown output in pandas. i tried many time but not able to do

Tags: python

```py
df1

A               B               C               D               Ouput 
789710756984    548886892221    350398300025    300025394048    test1
983654481934    517499889926    397484178171    178171940323    test33
919389880465    431272883458    883458919107                    test35
756910389077    418812155096    914202901745                    Not existing
450857107019    386837858855    933691130728    130728466224    Not existing
619824811591    988881665347                                    test7
596796725108    286295594202    260066341243    341243511988    test21
252278620500    200291299234    299234812303                    Not existing
234287694285    946115638974    858454512641                    test13
556303367635    117457961843    961843479545                    test15
722470934507    879241296559    140673622495                    test25
840651799191    944253660207    776475266291    266291276893    Not existing
586984130981    287511146718    146718930514                    test27
584984962231    374083203438    122321533594    533594529226    test17
210952447647    119358846116    132685932648    932648231206    test31
```

---

```py
df2

Phone_no    Name
789710756984    test1
397484178171    test3
883458919107    test5
619824811591    test7
260066341243    test9
533594529226    test11
858454512641    test13
117457961843    test15
374083203438    test17
341243511988    test19
596796725108    test21
286295594202    test23
140673622495    test25
146718930514    test27
932648231206    test29
132685932648    test31
178171940323    test33
431272883458    test35
```

Comment: Hi, can you maybe elaborate what exactly you're trying to do, or maybe simplify the example? I'd like to help, but I can't really understand what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You want to merge what with what else, on what key, how do you want to merge it (inner/left/right/full join), what's the desired output?

Comment: I suspect you just mean sort of a transformation of a single dataframe, could you then elaborate on the nature of logic of that transformation?

Comment: i want to lookup  df1's A,B,C,D columns in df2 but output should be in one column as shown in df1 output column. please let me know if question not clear.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, as well as what you have tried and why it failed.

Comment: @ Grzegorz Skibinski : i want to merge A,B,C,D columns in Phone_no,name in df1

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you can append your data. Also, you can get a meaningful result by using different merging approaches. Please follow the given link.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: i request you please do it once and i tried many times but not able to exactly as shown in output columns

Comment: Can you please provide me the expected results so that I could understand your query better?

Comment: i have df1 with A,B,C,D col with value phone num and on the other hand i have another df2 with phone_no, name col now i need to look up A,B,C,D columns in df2. i would like to add one more column in df1 and fetch the value from df2. how can we do it in pandas. it is similar to iferror....vlookup